# Generic zero for generic function

Tags: f#, inline

I have a function to calculate the cumulated sum of a sequence.

```
let cumsum<'T> = Seq.scan (+) 0 >> Seq.skip 1 >> Seq.toArray
```

Though it looks generic, the integer `0` makes it non-generic, and thus I cannot call the function with a sequence of floats.

Is there a generic zero that can replace my hardcoded `0`, or maybe a different way of making the function generic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [GenericZero](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370581.aspx) primitive but you need to make your function inline and make it explicitly a function (right now your function is written in [point-free style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)) since in principle values cannot be made inline.

```
let inline cumsum s = 
  s |> Seq.scan (+) LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero |> Seq.skip 1 |> Seq.toArray
```

Note that by removing the Type parameter `'T` the static member constraints are inferred automatically by the compiler:

```
val inline cumsum :
  s:seq< ^a> ->  ^b []
    when ( ^b or  ^a) : (static member ( + ) :  ^b *  ^a ->  ^b) and
          ^b : (static member get_Zero : ->  ^b)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
```

:)

Comment: Note that `cumsum` must be made an inline function rather than a value in order to have the intended effect, i.e. `let inline cumsum x = x |> Seq.scan (+) LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero |> Seq.skip 1 |> Seq.toArray`.

Comment: Didn't even have til to check reddit! :)

Comment: @ildjarn Why is that?

Comment: @lejon : Because values cannot be generic, and non-inline functions cannot be constrained to numeric types (a limitation of the CLI, not of F#).